# Replacing a string - Unknown flag at position

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My data look like:

```
df.head()

CLUID   STEP
9995    1998-10-27-03.18.54.256142  orders/sign()
9996    9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614  settings/user(?section=:section)
9997    9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614  settings/plugins
9998    1998-10-27-03.18.54.256142  saving/transactions
9999    9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614  settings/electronicstorage
```

I want to remove particular substring from column STEP.

I've tried:

```
df['STEP'] = df['STEP'].replace({'(?section=:section)': ''}, regex=True)
```

which raises:

> error: unknown flag at position 3

Expected output:

```
CLUID   STEP
9995    1998-10-27-03.18.54.256142  orders/sign()
9996    9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614  settings/user
9997    9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614  settings/plugins
9998    1998-10-27-03.18.54.256142  saving/transactions
9999    9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614  settings/electronicstorage
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: As @MayankPorwal asks: what would you like to happen? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65308530/edit) the expected output into the question.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Edited.

Comment: Try without `regex=True`.

Comment: @tevemadar It does nothing. Already tried before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub` may help. The backslash treats the character '?' as special.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'STEP': ["settings/user(?section=:section)", "orders/sign(/:orderIds)"]})

df['STEP'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('(\?section=:section)', '', str(x)))
```

Actually this works as well with `replace`:

```
df['STEP'] = df['STEP'].replace({'(\?section=:section)': ''}, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

> `(?aiLmsux)`
> (One or more letters from the set 'a', 'i', 'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x'.) [...]

(and there is `(?aiLmsux-imsx:...)` too)

That's why the 3rd position is wrong, `(?s` on positions 0-1-2 could be something valid, but the following `e` is not. `(?section=:section)` is not a valid regular expression.

---

`replace()` looks for exact string (and not substring) without regex, so you need regex, just escape the control characters:

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame({"CLUID":["1998-10-27-03.18.54.256142","9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614","9012-03-22-00.56.55.724614"],
                     "STEP":["orders/sign()","settings/user(?section=:section)","settings/plugins"]})
print(df)
df['STEP'] = df['STEP'].replace({'\(\?section=:section\)': ''}, regex=True)
print(df)
```

I see it's a couple minutes late, but worth mentioning, that the parentheses has to be escaped too.

Comment: But how should I deal with it? Is there any workaround?

Comment: @StanislavJirák so far I could not tell what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: I want to remove the substring as above from the column.